# When to call SplHeap::isCorrupted?

Tags: php, heap

The abstract class [`SplHeap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php) provides the [isCorrupted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splheap.iscorrupted.php) method:

> Tells if the heap is in a corrupted state
>
> ```
> public SplHeap::isCorrupted ( void ) : bool
> ```

I wonder how this method could be useful, let alone how a heap could get corrupted. One would expect that the internal heap implementation is solid, and would never get corrupted.

At first I thought that maybe there could be direct access to the underlying array, which would allow something like this (akin to what would be possible with Python's `heapq` implementation):

```php
$heap = new SplMinHeap();
$heap->insert(9);
$heap->insert(5);

echo $heap->top(); // 5

$heap[0] = 10; // make the heap inconsistent? -- not possible
```

The heap's internal data structure turns out to be *private*. A `var_dump` of the above heap, renders as follows:

```php
object(SplMinHeap)#1 (3) {
    ["flags":"SplHeap":private]=>int(0)
    ["isCorrupted":"SplHeap":private]=>bool(false)
    ["heap":"SplHeap":private]=>array(2) {
        [0]=>int(5)
        [1]=>int(9)
    }
}
```

As another possibility I thought that maybe memory constraints could lead to a corrupt heap, but in that case it seems more useful to let any of the modifying methods (`insert`, `extract`, ...) raise an exception, and leave the heap in its original state.

So my question is: Why would we ever need to call `$heap->isCorrupted()`, and in which scenario could it ever return `true`?

Answer (score 1):

A heap can get corrupted when an exception occurs in a user-defined `compare` function. The documentation on [SplHeap::compare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splheap.compare.php) has the following:

> **Warning** Throwing exceptions in `SplHeap::compare()` can corrupt the Heap and place it in a blocked state. You can unblock it by calling `SplHeap::recoverFromCorruption()`. However, some elements might not be placed correctly and it may hence break the heap-property.

For instance, this script will produce a corrupted heap:

```php
final class MySplHeap extends SplHeap {
    protected function compare($a, $b) {
        echo "compare $a with $b\n"; // Useful to see what is happening...
        if ($a === $b) return 0;
        if ($a > $b) return 1;
        throw new Exception("my error");
    }
}

$heap = new MySplHeap();

try {
    $heap->insert(3);
    $heap->insert(2);
    $heap->insert(1); 
    $heap->insert(4); // compare method raises error here
} catch(Exception $e) {}

var_dump($heap->isCorrupted()); // bool(true)

echo $heap->extract(); // RuntimeException: Heap is corrupted, heap properties are no longer ensured.
```

Due to the error, the value 4 could not be placed at the right spot in the heap.

The obvious remedy is to make sure that no exceptions occur in the comparison function.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I can now imagine how a heap gets corrupted. This could however just as well be handled with the `RuntimeException` in the last line, no? And additionally, am I right to assume the `recoverFromCorruption` method basicallly just re-runs the compare method on the heap?

Comment: Yes, it could be handled in the callback implementation with the `RuntimeException` (it was just an example -- errors could happen for a variety of reasons), but the point is that the heap implementation cannot know whether you've written a fail proof compare function (if you did, the heap will never get corrupted). As the `SqlHeap` code has no efficient way to deal with an error-throwing call of your callback function, it will leave the heap in a potentially "corrupted" state.  And yes, `recoverFromCorruption` will run the compare method again.